# php_value extension is ignored

Tags: php, apache, ioncube

I have a server that runs the bellow perfectly (Apache v2.2.14 & PHP v5.2)

Testing on new one the `zend_extension` is completely ignored but post_max_size is updated as should (Apache v2.2.22 PHP v5.4)

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
    php_value post_max_size 50M
    php_value zend_extension /<path>/ioncube_loader_lin_<php-version>.so
</VirtualHost>
```

If, however, I add IonCube to `php.ini` as

```
zend_extension = /path/ioncube_loader_lin_<php-version>.so
```

it works perfectly. I would like, however, to keep it on a per VirtualHost-basis. Does anyone have any ideia what could be causing this?

Comment: I doubt Apache could run distinct `mod_php` instances - which is what it would need to have one vhost without and one with loaded extension. (Zend extensions in particular should be enabled [in the php.ini anyway](http://xdebug.org/archives/xdebug-general/0286.html).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php), zend_extension is one of those directives that can't be set this way. It must be set in php.ini.

Comment: The page that explains what `PHP_INI_*` constants mean: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php (they are used all over the place in the page linked in the answer but that page doesn't contain any hint about their meaning).

Comment: Yet it works in the old server. Not only that Googling also shows success inserting `php_value zend_extension` both on .htaccess files and Apache .conf files. https://forum.jreviews.com/topic/816-activating-ioncube-php-loader-files-on-shared-servers-without-phpini-access/ - it could be somehing dropped from php 5.2 to 5.4 ?

Comment: @Frankie, dynamic loading using `dl` was disabled for mod_php and other sapis a few versions ago, because of the ton of issues associated with it. I can imagine that at the same time `zend_extension` was disabled as well. For what it's worth: it *always* was a bad idea to do this.